# In X-Men: Evolution, is Apocalypse associated to the power or technology of time travel?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-evolution

Years before, I have watched several episodes of The X-men: The Animated Series. And I saw how Apocalypse became the most formidable foe of the x-men because he has tapped the power of time travel.

Now in X-Men: Evolution, it seems Apocalypse was only given the power of energy manipulation from an alien craft.  Because I have not seen all the episodes yet in X-Men: Evolution, did the series associate Apocalypse to time travel?

Comment: OK.  So I hope somebody has gone through that series, otherwise, I still have to watch the episodes from time to time to check by myself. I want to make or describe to a more definite character/role the villain: Apocalypse.

Answer (score 1):

In the *X-Men: Evolution* series, we see a future Rama-Tut traveled back in time with an army to kill En Sabah Nur (Apocalypse as a child). The army is, of course, unsuccessful.

During the ensuing battles, Rama-Tut lost some of his equipment, only to be claimed by Apocalypse, who used the technology to augment himself. We do not, however, ever see Apocalypse use any of the technology to travel through time. Whether or not he possesses the technology is left unclear, but he never uses anything of the sort himself.

Even after Apocalypse is released and has his powers restored, he never utilizes time travel to prevent his imprisonment.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge as a long-time X-Men reader, Apocalypse has never really been associated with time-travel as a thing. In fact, he often goes into stasis for decades at a time in order to see what mutants will evolve into - kind of pointless if you have access to time travel. The association is probably from the various "Age of Apocalypse" storylines, but in those cases it was others who initiated alternate timelines, not Apocalypse himself.

Comment: The stories surrounding him sometimes involve time travel (e.g.: Cable), but Apocalypse doesn't do it himself, as far as I've seen.

Comment: Right - that's what I'm trying to say. Thanks for saying it better, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

No.  Apocalypse was not associated with time travel in X-men: Evolution.  I had to watch episodes 0408 and 0409 of it to confirm.  Thanks to the listing made in an answer to the question: [Which episodes of X-Men: Evolution cover the Apocalypse story arc?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46171/which-episodes-of-x-men-evolution-cover-the-apocalypse-story-arc), which gave me the idea to just watch the final 2 episodes of season 4.

But comparing to X-men: The Animated Series, as I recall Apocalypse got a hand of the power of time travel.  If my memory serves me right, Apocalypse was even able to capture all the psychics in the world to be able to achieve time control.  So, as a conclusion, the X-men: Evolution, comparing to the previous animated series, made it a different story-line for the villain Apocalypse.